# Getting error when trying to use workbox local files instead of CDN

Tags: service-worker, workbox

The situation is the following, I have been using workbox to precache files. It works locally, but when I upload my changes to an actual web page. I get the following error:

workbox-sw.js:1 Refused to load the script `https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.0.2/workbox-routing.prod.js` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: `https://api.paguetodo.com https://static.paguetodo.com`.

Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

So what I have been trying to do is using local Workbox files instead of CDN. When I perform the commands everything seems fine and the files are added to my project, but when I try to import them like this in my service worker file:

```
importScripts('workbox-v6.0.0/workbox-sw.js');
workbox.setConfig({
  modulePathPrefix: 'workbox-v6.0.0/'
});
```

I get the following error in the browser:

```
Strategy.js:143 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.q is not a function
    at w.v (Strategy.js:143)
```

Comment: Just modify your CSP to `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: https://api.paguetodo.com https://static.paguetodo.com https://storage.googleapis.com`. It will allow to load the `workbox-routing.prod.js` script.

Comment: You might want to look into https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers as an alternative way of using Workbox, without relying on loading additional scripts.